# import css from node js module

Tags: css, npm

I am using webpack, I can "import" the css file without error, but the css is not exported in the final product.

Webpack excerpt:

```
 module: {
    loaders: [
      {test: /\.css$/,loader: 'css-loader'},
      {test: /\.scss$/,loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')},
      {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', include},
      {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json', include},
      {test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i, loader: "file-loader" },
    ]
  },
```

Run:

```
npm install hopscotch
```

Code:

```
import 'hopscotch/dist/css/hopscotch.css';
```

Answer (score 1):

I was not using extract for the css files...

```
{test: /\.css$/,loader: 'css-loader'},
```

Should be:

```
{test: /\.css$/,loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader')},
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to your answer, you also need to add ExtractTextPlugin to the `plugins` array to define where to export the extracted CSS.

```
module: {
  loaders: [
    {test: /\.css$/,loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader')},
    {test: /\.scss$/,loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('css-loader!sass-loader')},
    {test: /\.js$/, loader: 'babel-loader', include},
    {test: /\.json$/, loader: 'json', include},
    {test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$/i, loader: "file-loader" },
  ]
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin({ filename: 'style.css' }),
  ],
},
```